# Radius of convergence of an infinite series by using a theorem.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion, power-series

Before I ask the question, I will explain a bit of theory and then give the question.

Theorem 3:
The derived series of a power series has the same radius of convergence as the original series.

The question is:
Find the radius of convergence $R$ of the following series by applying theorem 3.
The given serie is:
$\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} \binom{n}{2}z^{n} = z^{2} + 3z^{3} + 6z^{4} + 10z^{5} + ...$.

The solution (according to the book):
Differentiate the geometric series twice term by term and multiply the result by $\frac{z^2}{2}$. This yields the given series. Hence $R = 1$ by theorem 3.

I don't understand how theorem 3 gives the radius of convergence.

My question is if someone can explain this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The radius of convergence of the geometric series is equal $1.$ The radius does not change on differentiation. It does not change on multiplying by $z^2/2.$ Hence it is equal $1$ for the series in question.

Comment: Theorem 3 does not give the radius of convergence. It just tells you that the power series radius and the one that is differentiated will have the same radius. You still need to know what the original radius of convergence is (in this case it is 1).

Answer (score 1):

It is well known that the geometric series
$$1+z+z^2+z^3+\cdots$$
only converges for $|z|<1$. Now, if you derivate the radius of convergence doesn't change by Theorem 3. Also, multiplying by $z^2/2$ obviously doesn't change the radius of convergence.